# Case insensitive username check in JPQL

Tags: jpql, case-insensitive

I would like to create a case insensitive username check in my login process. A trivial NamedQuery gives back the User entity pass the test:

```
SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.userName LIKE :userName AND u.password = :password
```

But this LIKE not the LIKE that I would LIKE. It compares the userNames case sensitive. Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I have solved!

The NamedQuery:

```
SELECT u FROM UserWithRoles u WHERE LOWER( u.userName ) = :userName AND u.password = :password"
```

The bean code which sets the query up:

```
q.setParameter( "userName", userName_.toLowerCase() );
```